# Query to get top 2 and 3 rd Records from a Table

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a table list of Student:

```
Student         SECTION
student1        A
student2        A
student3        A
student4        A
student5        B
student6        B
student7        B
student8        B
```

I want to get total Randomly 5 Students
3 A Section Students and 
2 B Section Students

Done any once a Suggest a Simple SQL Query

Example : I want to club the below queries Randomly

```
select * from student where SECTION='A' LIMIT 3
select * from student where SECTION='B' LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close:

```
(select * from student where SECTION = 'A' order by rand() LIMIT 3
) union all
(select * from student where SECTION = 'B' order by rand() LIMIT 2
)
order by rand();
```

The subqueries use `order by rand()` to get random students with each grade.  The outer `order by rand()` randomizes the five students.

Note:  This is the simplest way to accomplish what you want.  If the `students` table is even moderately large and performance is an issue, there are alternative solutions.

Comment: if there are 2 A SECTION Records then i will get only 4 Records as Results Right, Can i Maintain Overal 5 Records which include both SECTION A & B if there are not enough students.

Can you Suggesst me a Solution

Comment: @Developer . . . That is quite a different question.  You should ask a different question and be very explicit about what you want the fifth record to be.  (You should not edit this question; two people have already answered it as it is and changing the question could invalidate the answers.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION` along `order by` like

```
(select * from student where SECTION='A' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
UNION
(select * from student where SECTION='B' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```