# Get a Students with 2 Different Limit Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table list of Student:

```
Student         SECTION
student1        A
student2        A
student3        A
student4        A
student5        B
student6        B
student7        B
student8        B
```

I want to get total Randomly 5 Students 3 A Section Students and 2 B Section Students

Case : if there are 2 A SECTION Records then I will get only 4 Records as Results Right, Can I Maintain Overall 5 Records which include both SECTION A & B if there are not enough students. Can you Suggest me a Solution

Done any once a Suggest a Simple SQL Query

Comment: mention expected output

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163360/get-list-of-specific-2-limits-of-records-from-single-table-in-single-query

Comment: This reads as though its been through an automatic translator, can you expand on what you want? Also, 'Random' is perhaps the most difficult thing to program, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Strawberry, That is also My Question, Its Different from This, Check Comments in that Page.

Comment: When asking a second question that follows on so closely from a previous question, it's polite to reference the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT student, section 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 1 seq, student, section FROM my_table WHERE section = 'a' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3) x
 UNION
     ( SELECT 2 seq, student, section FROM my_table WHERE section = 'b' )
 ORDER 
    BY seq, RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Looks Good, Means for first Query i will take 3 records , remaining from Second Query Right .?

Comment: Yes. In fact `seq` is not strictly necessary in this instance, as you can order by section,RAND() instead.